# Как вывести родительский атрибут?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как можно вывести родительский атрибут и атрибут самой страницы? Например: Главная - Каталог. На определённой странице?

Comment: Как хотите. Любым доступным способом.

Comment: Ну это понятно)

Comment: Ну ладно :< Это называется `хлебные крошки`. Если вы работаете на `WordPress`, то погуглите плагин, полюбому есть.

Comment: Какой атрибут?.

Comment: @Other Родительский и самой страницы

Comment: Что есть атрибут в данном случае? Название, хлебные крошки, средний цвет на странице, ID, ссылка на её комментарии? Всё это атрибуты.

Comment: У меня не получается

Comment: http://dimox.name/wordpress-breadcrumbs-without-a-plugin/